# Would I need a comma after the main clause here?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, american-english, commas

Would I need a comma before the word "as" in this sentence?

> The word "fear" also takes a new meaning(,) as it comes to represent a more self-centered notion.

Comment: The word 'as' is ambiguous between the senses 'because' and 'within the timeframe during which'; the insertion of a comma could be argued not to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have two independent clauses here separated by a conjunction.  In those cases, a comma is necessary.  ("As" can be many parts of speech, but in this case the use is that of a conjunction.)

> The word "fear" also takes a new meaning, *as* it comes to represent a more self-centered notion.
>   The electric chair seemed an ironic choice of execution, *as* the sentenced dictator was responsible for establishing the first power plant in the country.

However, your independent clauses are so interconnected, my suggestion is contract the sentence (which also removes the need for a comma).

> The word "fear" also takes a new meaning as a more self-centered notion.

Context of the rest of the surrounding sentences could clear that up more.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that the flow of the words together seem perfect without a comma.

However, while speaking out the same sentence, a short pause after 'meaning' would render the speech a bit more articulation.

Answer (score -1):

The comma is a matter of style. I would include it because it helps the flow of the sentence, but ultimately it's up to you (or your preferred style manual).